# Dynamically change TextBlock in Style

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm new to WPF, I have created a custom ToggleButton with a custom style.

[image: Button]

The ToggleButton (in a xaml) :

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="checkBox" Style="{DynamicResource ToggleButtonStyleOnOff}"/>
```

style (in an other xaml -> Style.xaml) :

```
<!--  Button ON / OFF -->
<Style x:Key="ToggleButtonStyleOnOff" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Border x:Name="onBorder" ...>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="onText" Text="On"/>
                </Border>
                <Border x:Name="offBorder" ...>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="offText" Text="Off"/>
                 </Border>
            </StackPanel>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                    <Setter .../>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                    <Setter .../>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

How can I change the Text content of a TextBlock dynamically (from a file with the content in different language) ?

As I understood it's impossible to change the style content at run time. Is it true ? What are my solutions if I want to change the text ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set custom values on ToggleButton level:

```
<ToggleButton Content="Yes" Tag="No" x:Name="checkBox" Style="{DynamicResource ToggleButtonStyleOnOff}"/>
```

and bind to them in template (style can also provide default values):

```
<!--  Button ON / OFF -->
<Style x:Key="ToggleButtonStyleOnOff" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
<Setter Property="Content" Value="On"/>
<Setter Property="Tag" Value="Off"/>
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Border x:Name="onBorder" >
                    <TextBlock x:Name="onText" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                </Border>
                <Border x:Name="offBorder" >
                    <TextBlock x:Name="offText" Text="{TemplateBinding Tag}"/>
                 </Border>
            </StackPanel>
```

Comment: I did not even knew that you could do that, thank's a lot !